# Export Headers while building NDK Shared Library

Tags: java, android, c++, build, android-ndk

i'm trying to build a shared library i can distribute. This File should roughly have the form of an Apple *.framework file. What's important with that is that all headers i mention in the "LOCAL_C_INCLUDES" variable are exported (copied) to a certain location. Finally i want my library file to look like this:

```
LIB_ROOT/
         myLib.so
         include/
                 header1.hpp
                 header2.hpp
```

I can't find an easy method to do this with the NDK build. Sure i could try to pass my Application LOCAL_C_INCLUDES variables and glob all the header files but that looks pretty ugly. I figures other people must have solved this problem. How did you do?

The only thing i could find on the internet was this line:

```
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES = $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
```

in the Android.mk file, which does roughly nothing at all. What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this script at the end of my makefile to manually copy headers in my directory:

all: $(PROJECT_PATH)/include/$(notdir $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE))

$(PROJECT_PATH)/include/$(notdir $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE)): $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE)
    mkdir -p $(PROJECT_PATH)/include
    cp $< $@
    cp $(LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS) $(PROJECT_PATH)/include